# Qt Display button on top of image

Tags: c++, qt

I need to display a button on top of an image. Something similar to

[image]

The background is a QPixmap/QImage and the button is a QPushbutton. I need to be able to dynamically change the image - so I am not sure if a stylesheet would be suitable for the task. I tried [this](http://ahmadferdous.blogspot.com/2009/05/qt-set-background-image-of-custom.html), but could not get it to work.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Subclass QWidget and implement paintEent where you can paint your image at the background. Set and change background image by stylesheet also possible.
2. Add layout with button to this widget.

There are something like this:

```
class WidgetWithButton
  : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QImage m_bgImage;
public:
  WidgetWithButton(QWidget* aParent)
    : QWidget(aParent)
  {
    QHBoxLayout* l = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QPushButton* myButton = new QPushButton(tr("Close"));
    l->addWidget( myButton, 0, Qt::AlignCenter );
  }
  void setImage(const QImage& aImage)
  {
    m_image = aImage;
    update();
  }
protected:
  virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* aPainEvent)
  {
    if (m_image.isValid())
    {
      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.drawImage(rect(), m_image);
    }
    else
      QWidget::paintEvent(aPainEvent);
  }
};
```